# How to convert https curl into php curl code

Tags: php, curl

I am new to curl and working on project on php. I trying to run curl command on php and my curl command is

> curl -I -X POST --header "ttl: 60" "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/gAAAAABXIvgcjhN-7l1yphdkMoubnwZJdeLKG6cGxG_TeHxZ_BGNDKgoKbhB306PTgvcgFJjurkUI14qIIJ4oZDYyKlJO7oYVZrzyjUI4cKUjtiZlnTXKj0tf9XiXUICtpjRqGqXoMLI"

I had this code to execute this curl as shown below

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('ttl: 60'));

$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

but not found solution yet. My question is how to convert this curl into php curl
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Comment: Your `curl` command and php code are different, in that, PHP does not use curl but instead `libcurl` - `/usr/local/bin/curl` *(or your local path)* is merely  an interface from the cli to also run `libcurl` - they are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As William suggested add CURLOPT_POST in your code.

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('ttl: 60'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In your curl command -X referring to data type POST or GET and --header or -H is a extra header include in curl.
You can refer [curl parameter description](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for more details on it.